# Driver Information Display Brightness Reversed

Tags: dodge, lights, dashboard

2016 Dodge Dart Rallye

This is something I have never encountered before, and can't find much info on.

The Driver Info Display brightness started acting up after heavy braking in snow on hills (not sure if related at all to the problem). The digital screen area only has inverted brightness. The analog gauges are all as they were, as is the infotainment area (i.e. these are normal and are not being affected in the same way). Now, when using the dimmer knob, here is what I see:

Knob all the way up: the cabin lights come on normally, and the infotainment and dash lights are max brightness except the digital display section. I am able to turn the cabin lights off by turning the knob slightly, as you would expect.

Knob all the way down: no cabin light, and all dash and infotainment lights are as dim as they can be, as expected, except for the digital display section, which looks to be max brightness.

It doesn't appear the screen is bad because it can look normal if the knob is turned down, and because it is still working, I don't know if a fuse would be the issue. Turning the car off and back on does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While not the optimal solution, have you tried disconnecting the battery for a period of time? This may be a Body Control Module (BCM) issue. Cutting the power and allowing the system to drain (a good 20-30 minutes should do it) might reset everything. Doesn't solve the overall issue of "why did this do this", but might get you back to jump street of it working correctly. Note, this will reset everything in the car, including the radio (might cause it to look for a radio code, so have it handy prior to if needed).

Comment: That's definitely gone a bit sideways! Sounds as if the DID has gotten itself in a twist with it's brightness settings. Probably worth going into the Display settings and checking what they are set to and perhaps cycling between manual and auto modes to see if it sets it back in line.

Comment: Can that be some strange feature? E.g. Knob all the way up, which means it's dark and the display should be dim in order to not blind the driver. And knob all the way down, which means it's not that dark and you don't need the dash to be lighted, therefore the display gets brighter to be more visible.

Comment: @Ghukas Sort of but not quite - Turning the dimmer all the way up until it "clicks" engages what Dodge calls "Parade Mode", this turns on the interior cabin lights (as the OP describes) and sets the DID to "Day" brightness mode (overriding the normal behavior of using the headlight state to determine brightness). The brightness value for "Day" can be set in the DID "Display" settings.

Comment: But of course that's still no explanation for why this would suddenly present.

Comment: I'm a certified tech and a Mopar salesman. Mine just started doing this today. My Dart is under warranty, service gets to fix it. I will let you know what the prognosis is and if there is anything you can do to fix it. I imagine that it is going to require a flash update, but no real evidence yet. We will all know shortly!